# Excel Advanced Filter Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I used to use Excel Advanced Filter to copy data across because it has a beautiful (to me) side effect - clear up the copy to range before it place the result.

Just now I have troubles to having the advanced filter to return the entire range of data without critiera range being specified.

```
FilterRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Data.Range("BA1:BA2"), _
    CopyToRange:=Data.Range("B1:AK1"), Unique:=False
FilterRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Data.Range("B1:AK1"), Unique:=False
```

Cell BA1 has the name of one of the columns in the source FilterRange and cell BA2 is empty.
The first filter will return all the data because there is no specific criteria specified. 
And the strangest thing happen - the second filter give me 1 row of data!
The behavior is very consistent. I have keep comment one and the other out from the macro and the filters behave the same way.

Is it possible that Excel has some hidden criteria range I need to track and clean up?

Comment: the question is what do you want to achieve with the second line? Why do you want to filter if you not passing any criteria? Moreover, I see that the second line keeps filtering criteria set for the first line which makes me thinking to use AdvancedFilter carefuly. BTW, is this code complete or there are some other lines in between (which could impact the result and answer to your question).

Comment: @KazJaw - thx for your comment! actually it is the second line i use to copy the data. but it doesn't work as expected - only one row of data returned. so i change it to become the first line and then it worked. i raised this question because the second line works fine in my other macros just don't understand what's wrong with this particular one.